# PHP DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

I trying to get the "link" elements from certain webpages. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong though. I'm getting the following error:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]:
>   htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 536
>
> Filename: controllers/test.php
>
> Line Number: 34

Line 34 is the following in the code:

> ```
>       $dom->loadHTML($html);
> ```

my code:

```
            $url = "http://www.amazon.com/";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    if($html = curl_exec($ch)){

        // parse the html into a DOMDocument
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $dom->recover = true;
        $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;

        $dom->loadHTML($html);

        $hrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($hrefs);
        echo "</pre>";

        curl_close($ch);


    }else{
        echo "The website could not be reached.";
    }
```

Comment: Changed to a google friendly url. Revert it back if its not appropriate for you..

Comment: Could you see this? [why-would-does-this-error-handling-function-cause-domdocument-to-hang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129115)

Answer (score 42):

It means some of the HTML code is invalid.
THis is just a warning, not an error. Your script will still process it. To suppress the warnings set

```
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

Or you could just completely suppress the warning by doing

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

Comment: Are you sure you set libxml_use_internal_errors(true); at the top of the php script? I also updated  my answer to provide another alternative

Comment: that hides the warning, but it's returning an empty object

Comment: That is weird. I ran your exact code and it worked fine. It returned a bunch of objects. Your print_r statement outputted DOMNodeList Object
(
    [length] => 81
)

Comment: -1 For suggesting suppression of all errors on that line. This will lead to a debugging nightmare. I would have given you a +1 if it were not for that.

Comment: @Gerry , Kris is wrong in one thing - script will not process things you wanted (it will skip them), @ operator not only hides messages, it is also forcing the script to proceed anyway - this might be little dangerous BUT in times like loading some shi*t*ty html it can be the most powerful tool :)

Comment: this is an awful solution, NEVER do this....if you want to supress error output to the browser, you could do something like ob_start();...commands here....$buf=ob_get_clean() and then check $buf for any error output which will let you keep the errors, but stop the browser output

Answer (score 15):

This may be caused by a rogue `&` symbol that is immediately succeeded by a proper tag. As otherwise you would receive a missing `;` error. See: [Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685277/warning-domdocumentloadhtml-htmlparseentityref-expecting-in-entity).

The solution is to - replace the `&` symbol with `&amp;`
or if you must have that `&` as it is then, *may be* you could enclose it in: `<![CDATA[` - `]]>`

Comment: In my case I outputted a variable containing an ampersand between `<td>` tags i.e. `$variable['ingredient'] = "7 & 8";  $tbody .= "<td>" . $variable['ingredient'] . "</td>";` which lead to this error: `Message: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity`.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is poorly formed.  If formed poorly enough loading the HTML into the DOM Document might even fail.  If loadHTML is not working then suppressing the errors is pointless.  I suggest using a tool like HTML Tidy to "clean up" the poorly formed HTML if you are unable to load the HTML into the DOM.

HTML Tidy can be found here http://www.htacg.org/tidy-html5/