# How to get a json array of the text within a class?

Tags: php, json

The html snippet in a url (www.foo.com/index.html):

```
...
<th class="name" align="left" scope="col">
<a class="foo" href="foo.html">foo</a>
</th>
...
<th class="name" align="left" scope="col">
<a class="bar" href="bar.html">bar</a>
</th>
...
<th class="name" align="left" scope="col">
<a class="ba" href="baz.html">baz</a>
</th>
......
```

I would like to get, through php all the text inside the class `.name` and convert it to JSON

So that it ends up like:

```
{"names":["foo","bar","baz"]}
```

---

This is what I have tried:

```
function linkExtractor($html){
    $nameArr = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $names = //how do i get the elements?
    foreach($names as $name) {
        array_push($nameArr, $name);
    }
    return $imageArr;
}

echo json_encode(array("names" => linkExtractor($html)));
```

Comment: why don't you try jquery ?

Comment: @Dwza Won'T work since the html is not being executed...

Comment: You normally do that with xpath. Please use the search before asking a question.

Comment: @hakre how in any way is that a duplicate?

Comment: @Maximilian: Exactly for this: `//how do i get the elements?` in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this ...

```
$html = "http://www.foo.com/index.html"; //is this right?
function linkExtractor($html, $classname){
    $nameArr = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $names = $doc->xpath("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

    foreach($names as $name) {
        array_push($nameArr, $name);
    }
    return $imageArr;
}

echo json_encode(array("names" => linkExtractor($html,".name")));
```

Comment: and before you try this, rest assured that it won't work.

Comment: I am getting the error `Missing argument 2 for linkExtractor(),`

Comment: use edited version of answer ...

Comment: @Maximilian: That error only prevented you from getting the next fatal error. See the linked duplicate on how to actually run that xpath query.

Comment: Why does this not work? it seems like it should?

Comment: @Anri still no luck with the update?

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 16 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/jsonnames.php on line 8

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 18 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/jsonnames.php on line 8

Comment: can you try again to put ; end of this **$html = "http://www.foo.com/index.html"**

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 16 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/jsonnames.php on line 8

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 18 in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/jsonnames.php on line 8

Comment: @Anri this is my new error above!

Comment: take a look at **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328322/php-domdocumentloadhtml-domdocument-loadhtml-htmlparseentityref-no-name** and **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685277/warning-domdocumentloadhtml-htmlparseentityref-expecting-in-entity**  I think you have some other errors as well

Comment: Okay now i am just getting this error

Comment: @Anri Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::query() in /home/content/57/9770557/html/untitled folder/jsonnames.php on line 8

Comment: instead of query try xpath see updated version ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52308/discussion-between-maximilian-and-anri)

Answer (score 0):

So just this has an end:

```
$names = function($html) {
    $doc  = new DOMDocument();
    $last = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors($last);
    $xp     = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($xp->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' name ')]") as $node)
        $result[trim($node->textContent)] = 1;
    return array_keys($result);
};

echo json_encode(array("names" => $names($html)));
```

Output:

```
{"names":["foo","bar","baz"]}
```

Required PHP version: 5.3+

Comment: this returns nothing.

Comment: like this `{"names":[]}`

Comment: If you see that output, it means that it generally works, however the HTML is not as you wrote in your question. As you can see it perfectly works: http://3v4l.org/3TUPb - So if you provide HTML that does not contain such (e.g. by beign plain invalid so DOM refuses to load), fix the HTML first. You're probably just having some HTML problem, totally unrelated to traverse the nodes.